# commands.getoutput() raises Errno 12 - Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python

I have a Python script which runs on a server with RHEL5. The server has 32GB memory and 8 Intel Xeon CPUs at 2.83GHz. I think the hardware resource should not be a problem, but when I attempt to upload and process a 15 million line text file, the program gives me an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 511, in <module>
    startup()
  File "./test.py", line 249, in startup
    cmdoutput = commands.getoutput(cmd_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/commands.py", line 46, in getoutput
    return getstatusoutput(cmd)[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/commands.py", line 55, in getstatusoutput
    pipe = os.popen('{ ' + cmd + '; } 2>&1', 'r')
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I have investigated this problem and did not found any answers that exactly match my problem. Those answers were focused on the "popen" subroutine, but I do not use this routine. I just use the "`commands.getoutput()`" to display the file type of a document.

It should be noted that if I try to process a 10 million line text, this problem does not happen. It only happens when the text file is large.
Can any people help me out on this issue? The answer could be a better module other than the "`command.getoutput()`". Thanks!

Comment: Try looking at subprocess.Popen.  I'm not sure, but I think your problem is related to the fact that commands.getoutput will attempt to hold all the output in memory and return it at once.  Avoid that approach.

Comment: What does the command do with the file? Does it read it all into memory and do some local operations? Does it output a whole bunch to the console, for which your script would be reading a lot of data?

Comment: Look again to the traceback, you actually use os.popen implicitly (getoutput() calls it)

Comment: You can use `ulimit -a` to check that the current per-process memory limits are what you expect.

Comment: Ummm a little back of the napkin math...my single line (of arbitrary length) txt file on my desktop takes 135 bytes. 135 bytes x 15,000,000 lines = 2,025,000,000 bytes = 1977539.025 kilobytes = 1931.19 megabytes = 1.89...gigabytes. What is the maximum memory usage of the python interpreter? I have no clue if this could be it or not (thus the comment, not an answer) but maybe you're butting up against some sort of OS/interpreter limit when loading the entire thing into memory?

Comment: @IamChuckB: I don't think that is the issue. a 32-bit python process would probably be 2GB, and a 64-bit python process would obviously be higher. I think AjitGeorge has the closest guess with the PIPE size

Comment: You should read the file line-by-line and not at once into memory (what I understood from _upload and process_); otherwise you'll run into issues when there are multiple processes fighting for the same limited resource (RAM in your case). You may get it to work once, but then next time it will run out of memory again.

Answer (score 2):

1. your command might consume too much memory. To check, run it with the large file from a console without python to see if you get any errors
2. your command might generate too much output. To check, run:

   ```
   subprocess.check_call(["cmd", "arg1", "arg2"])
   ```

   if it succeeds then you should read output incrementally and discard the processed output e.g. line by line:

   ```
   p = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "arg1", "arg2"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
       # do something with line
       print line,
   p.stdout.close()
   exit_code = p.wait() # wait for the process to exit
   ```